# communication between talend jobs through webservices

Tags: rest, esb, talend

i am begginner and i want to make this scenario with Talend Open Studio For ESB
1) Retrieve ID's for attributs from a table in my database
2) Iterate through each ID and make a call to a webservice
3) Call the webservice method with the ID, and retrieve results
4) Output results for each ID into an XML file or some kind of output which can be manipulated further by another job .

Is there any suggestion to do this job ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can totally do this with TOS ESB. Try tRESTClient component to call your external Webservice (step 2&3). If you want your scenario to be a REST service itself, you can have a look at this demo for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt2dMCNBW2g

Comment: thank you for your reply,i've made something similar to the video tutorial ( in my job i 'he made trestRequest --TxmlMap--trestResponse 
 and in my tXMLMap component i've added two schema of 2 tables from my Oracle database  but unfortunetly, i've got my webservice published without giving me any result ...this is the url of my webservice :http://localhost:8088/valeur/2 and when i test it with advanced RestClient i 've got 200 status but the result was empty how could i resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your current work.

Comment: my problem is resolved thank you :)i have published my webservice successfully,myproblem now is to find a way to consume those data and print them in an xml file , which component can i choose ??